# C# script cannot be executed in my job when deployed from ssis to Sql server

Tags: c#, sql-server, ssis

I have a C# script task in my SSIS package that I can run on my computer without any problem. But when I deploy it on my server and execute the package from the sql job I get an error. With the try/catch clause I get this in a txt file:

```
Message :Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {00024500-0000-0000-C000-000000000046} failed due to the following error: 80040154 Class not registered (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80040154 (REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG)).<br/>
StackTrace :   at System.RuntimeTypeHandle.CreateInstance(RuntimeType type, Boolean publicOnly, Boolean noCheck, Boolean& canBeCached, RuntimeMethodHandleInternal& ctor, Boolean& bNeedSecurityCheck)
   at System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceSlow(Boolean publicOnly, Boolean skipCheckThis, Boolean fillCache, StackCrawlMark& stackMark)
   at System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceDefaultCtor(Boolean publicOnly, Boolean skipCheckThis, Boolean fillCache, StackCrawlMark& stackMark)
   at System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type, Boolean nonPublic)
   at System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type)
   at ST_86c290165eda4c9a962b68fdf181801f.ScriptMain.Main()
```

Can somebody explain me what the problem is please?

The drivers ACE.OLEDB 12.0 and 16.0 are installed on the server (SQL server 2014 SP2 CU11)

How can I change my script to change font without using interop ?

Here is my C# script

```
#region Namespaces
using System;
using System.Data;
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;
#endregion

namespace ST_86c290165eda4c9a962b68fdf181801f
{
    [Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Tasks.ScriptTask.SSISScriptTaskEntryPointAttribute]
    public partial class ScriptMain : Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Tasks.ScriptTask.VSTARTScriptObjectModelBase
    {   
        public void Main()
        {
                String FilePath = Dts.Variables["User::excelPath"].Value.ToString();
                Excel.Application excelApp = new Excel.Application();
                Excel.Workbook excelWorkbook = excelApp.Workbooks.Open(FilePath);
                Excel.Sheets excelSheets = excelWorkbook.Worksheets;

                Excel.Worksheet excelWorksheet = (Excel.Worksheet)excelSheets.get_Item(1);
                Excel.Range excelCell = (Excel.Range)excelWorksheet.Cells;
                excelCell.Font.Name = "Arial";
                excelWorkbook.Save();
                excelWorkbook.Close(true);
                excelApp.Quit();
                System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(excelApp);
        Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Success;
        }

        #region ScriptResults declaration
        enum ScriptResults
        {
            Success = Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.DTSExecResult.Success,
            Failure = Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.DTSExecResult.Failure
        };
        #endregion

    }
}
```

Comment: The error sounds like due to driver version related issue. Have you tried with X86 (32bit)

Comment: The `excelApp` var is trying to use the Excel app (via COM), not it's drivers.  I would assume the Excel itself is not installed on the server, which is common.  The drivers allow you to import/export to/from Excel as a data source.  They don't provide access to the Excel app object model.

Comment: Because Excel is a client app it's not a good idea to install on a server.  Instead, use a data flow task to read/write to/from an Excel spreadsheet.  If you need to change fonts, add pivot tables etc then create a template Excel workbook.  Copy/paste using a file system task and then export data into the copy (again via a data flow task - which uses the drivers you have installed).

Comment: @destination-data I already have a template but when I copy it and fill this copy the font is not the one I set before

Comment: AFAIK you can't set the font via driver/data flow tasks.  I would have expected the import to respect the font on the target range.  However, if it doesn't you can always import data into one tab and display in another, via formulas/pivot tables etc.  Of course, that's a bit clunky.  You can install Excel on the server but Microsoft [does not recommend this](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/257757/considerations-for-server-side-automation-of-office).  Have you considered [Export-Excel](https://github.com/dfinke/ImportExcel)?

Answer (score 0):

The CLSID {00024500-0000-0000-C000-000000000046} refers to Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.

I'd suggest you need to install Excel on your server. I don't know if there is a specific 'Interop' installation but it may be available in Excel's custom setup.